# WCF REST service response error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

This is my service interface.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =      
WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "SampleMethod")]
    ResultObject SampleMethod(Stream inputStream);
```

`SampleMethod` returns `ResultObject` (present in App_Code) whose structure is:

```
public class ResultObject
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public Object Value { get; set; }

    public ResultObject()
    {
        StatusCode = 200; // OK
    }
}
```

I'm getting following exception

`"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."`

inner exceptions:

`Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

Comment: Is that exception on the client side? If so, are you seeing anything on the server side?

Comment: @JonSkeet, error on client side. I logged the result on server. Result is fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet, instead of `ResultObject`, if I set return type as string and serialize my ResultObject in the method, it works fine. it adds those backslashes I don't want.

Comment: What is `Value` set to? And have you looked at the result on the wire (e.g. with Wireshark)? Presumably when you say you've logged the result on the server, that's *before* it tries to convert it to JSON...

Comment: I'll check in Wireshark. btw, logged result is `{"StatusCode":422,"Value":{"IsExists":false,"Id":null}}` and you are right. I'm putting JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj) to log the result. So it is before wcf json conversion.